# Best way to switch between static assets and CDN based assets for development and deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing and application in ASP.NET MVC3. I am planning to take advantage of Amazons Cloudfront offering as a CDN to serve static assets.

I am curious if anyone has devised a simple method for switching between local assets for development and CDN based assets for deployment?

Any tips or tricks would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similarly to Paul's answer.

In the past I've used an extension method for UrlHelper that created the links based on a value from the web.config.

This is helpful so you don't have to minipulate your views after publishing, and it's as simple as updating a web.config entry on publish. Any resources that require using the CDN resource, you simply say `Url.CdnContent("~/site.css")`

I'm not on my development pc at the moment, but when I get home, I'll get you the source for my extension method

It's very simplistic, but it works for what I need it to do

```
public static string CdnContent(this UrlHelper helper, string relativePath)
{
    var cdnRoot = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cygnus.cdnroot"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cdnRoot))
        return UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(relativePath, helper.RequestContext.HttpContext);

    if (relativePath.StartsWith("~"))
        relativePath = relativePath.Substring(1);

    if (cdnRoot.EndsWith("/"))
        cdnRoot = cdnRoot.Substring(0, cdnRoot.Length - 1);

    if (!relativePath.StartsWith("/"))
        relativePath = "/" + relativePath;

    return cdnRoot + relativePath;
}
```

Comment: That would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: @stephen776 if you look at the source code, it's setup to work without the web.config value as well. I leave out the cdnroot appsetting when I'm developing locally, then have my web config transforms add it in at build time.

Answer (score 4):

I've done it in the past using a few simple rules:

- Always use file relative paths in CSS
- Always use a standard pattern to reference content in your views (I use application relative paths with `Url.Content`, ie. `Url.Content("~/content/file.jpg")`)
- Do not reference files in JavaScript.

Then in my deploy process I can simply copy all static assets from the site to the CDN, the CSS will just work since its relative (CSS `url()` values are always relative to the CSS file they are in, not the request), and I will use regex to replace any strings in my views that are in the form I expect to have the CDN base path.

Answer (score 2):

*Nice question*. I suggest you use **Conditional Compilation Variables**.

If your project is in **debug mode**, local assets would be linked. If your project is in **release mode**, CDN assets would be linked.

Here is a sample:

```
<head runat="server">
    <% #if DEBUG %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Assets/Styles/Default.css" />
    <% #else %>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.mysite.com/Assets/Styles/Default.css" />
    <% #endif %>
</head>
```

But be careful, when you **publish you project**, it should be in **release mode**. Once, I updated one of my projects and it was in DEBUG mode and everything went wrong.

Here are some nice links about Conditional Compilation:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2005/12/01/conditional-compilation-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/09/24/more-on-conditional-compilation-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: This seems straightforward enough. Thanks for the info. I will check out all of the links

Answer (score 1):

I have a set of extension methods I use (see below). You can use these as a base/example to create your own custom debug/release extension methods.

General debug/release:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DebugReleaseString(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string debugString, string releaseString)
{
    string toReturn = debugString;
#if !DEBUG
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(releaseString))
        toReturn = releaseString;
#endif
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(toReturn);
}
```

General debug/release usage:

```
@Html.DebugReleaseString("/images/myimage.jpg", "http://mycdn.com/images/myimage.jpg")
```

Debug/release CSS tags:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CssTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName)
{
    return html.CssTag(fileName, string.Empty);
}

public static MvcHtmlString CssTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName, string releaseFileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    string cssTag = string.Format(
        "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"{0}\" />",
        html.MeDebugReleaseString(fileName, releaseFileName));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(cssTag);
}
```

Debug/release CSS tags usage:

```
@Html.CssTag("/styles/mystyle.css")
@Html.CssTag("/styles/mystyle.css", "http://mycdn.com/styles/mystyle.css")
```

Debug/release JS tags:

```
public static MvcHtmlString JavascriptTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName)
{
    return html.JavascriptTag(fileName, string.Empty);
}

public static MvcHtmlString JavascriptTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName, string releaseFileName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    string jsTag = string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"{0}\"></script>",
                                 html.MeDebugReleaseString(fileName, releaseFileName));

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(jsTag);
}
```

Debug/release JS tags usage:

```
@Html.JavascriptTag("/scripts/myscript.css")
@Html.JavascriptTag("/scripts/myscript.css", "http://mycdn.com/scripts/myscript.js")
```

Additional debug/release options:

```
public enum RenderModeEnum
{
    Debug,
    Release,
    DebugAndRelease
}

public static MvcHtmlString CssTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName, RenderModeEnum tagRenderMode)
{
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.DebugAndRelease)
        return html.CssTag(fileName);

#if DEBUG
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.Debug)
        return html.CssTag(fileName);
#else
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.Release)
        return html.CssTag(fileName);
#endif

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}

public static MvcHtmlString JavascriptTag(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string fileName, RenderModeEnum tagRenderMode)
{
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.DebugAndRelease)
        return html.JavascriptTag(fileName);

#if DEBUG
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.Debug)
        return html.JavascriptTag(fileName);
#else
    if (tagRenderMode == RenderModeEnum.Release)
        return html.JavascriptTag(fileName);
#endif

    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Additional debug/release options usage:

```
@Html.CssTag("/styles/mystyle.css", RenderModeEnum.DebugAndRelease)
@Html.CssTag("/styles/mystyle.css", RenderModeEnum.Debug)
@Html.CssTag("http://mycdn.com/styles/mystyle.css", RenderModeEnum.Release)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a library specifically to tackle this problem.

https://github.com/vincpa/mvc.resourceloader